# Parameters to the Firebase Push Messaging System

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Push notification its works fine but i have a question what if,

> I need the ability to provide parameters to the Firebase push
>   messaging system that will allow me to display a message that, when
>   clicked, goes to a specified web link - in a web view. Most
>   importantly, this needs to function when the user does not have the
>   app loaded.

Is it possible ?? I gone through the documentation of firebase but didn't get anything about it.

Comment: What do you mean with "the user does not have the app loaded"? 1) The app is not installed -> no Firebase Push possible 2) The app is not running -> you can send key-value pairs with the data field

Comment: app is not running @3dmg

Answer (score 3):

For sending notifications to a user when they might not have the app running, use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

For sending messages to a user when they might not have the app installed, use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) or [Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/).

Comment: i know about it but can i send the weblink along with it ??

Comment: You could send a data message, have your service handle that, then open a web view. And `click_action` may work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: i am using firebase plugin in my ionic app

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to try "Advance options" under the pushnotification by sending the key value pair like following(`link` is parameter and you set this parameter value in `firebase console`):

```
    window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen ((notification) {
      if notification.link != '' && notification.tap == true
      ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(notification.link, '_blank', 'location=yes')
            window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open 
}
```